# Integrating RFT Test framework to work with RQM

Tags: rft

I designed a framework in RFT where the test cases are written in spreadsheet specifying the data source, object and keyword and a driver script which processes through all this data and routes it to the appropriate method for each test step all in a spreadsheet. Now I want to integrate this with RQM so that each of my test cases in the spreadsheet is shown as passed/failed in RQM. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement now an algorithm to read those testcases in the spreadsheet and pass them to RQM as attachments with logTestResult.

```
 For example: 
     logTestResult( <your attachment> , true );
```

And if you are already connected to RQM the adapter will attach files that you indicate automatically to RQM. So, at the end you will see step by step the results and if the script ends correctly RQM will show you the script as "passed".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer Juan. I solved this by passing the testcase name from Script Argument part of RQM and fetching the arguments in my starter script as shown below:-

```
public void testMain(Object[] args) throws Exception 
{
    String n=args[0].toString();
    logInfo("Parameter from RQM"+n);

    ModuleDriver d=new ModuleDriver();
    d.execute_main(n);

}
```

Since I have verification points setup for each of the steps in my test cases the results get reported based on each of those verification points in RQM which is what i needed.